# What is the dimension of a topology?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, vector-spaces

We know about the manifold dimensions of topological objects. I have a query, as every vector space has Hamel basis and the dimension of a vector space is defined as the number of elements in the basis set. My question is why this definition of dimension is not used to defined the basis of a topological space. Is that the reason, a topological space may not have same number of elements in its every basis?

Comment: you define dimension for non-vector-space objects via (local) homeomorphisms to an object you know the dimension of (subsets of vector spaces.) therefore you need that 'dimension' is invariant under such mappings.

Comment: You should not be confused by the fact that the word basis is used in both cases. A basis in linear algebra and a basis in topology are two very different sorts of objects, and serve different purposes. In any case, clearly $\Bbb R^n$ should have dimension $n$, but the smallest basis you can get for the standard topology is countable.

Comment: In my terminology topologies have a base, while vector spaces have a basis.

Comment: There are several types of topological dimension: E.g The small inductive dimension $ind,$ the large inductive dimension $Ind,$  and the covering dimension.  For the space $\mathbb R^n$ these are equal to $n$. Heed the comment from Mike Miller.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your idea, of defining the dimension using a basis of a topological space, does not work [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)#Definition_and_basic_properties)]:

> However, a base is not unique. Many bases, even of different sizes, may generate the same topology. [...] In contrast to a basis of a vector space in linear algebra, a base need not be maximal; indeed, the only maximal base is the topology itself. In fact, any open set generated by a base may be safely added to the base without changing the topology.

Your idea now might be: "let's take the smallest possible basis and define the dimension as the cardinality of that basis". This is actually the **weight** of a topology [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)#Definition_and_basic_properties)]:

> The smallest possible cardinality of a base is called the weight of the topological space.

This is a topological invariant, so you *could* do this. But then the topological dimension then will rarely (if ever) agree with other definitions of dimension, as @MikeMiller mentioned in his comment.

In case you want to know how topologists usually define the (topological) dimension of a topological space, first recall the concepts of *order* and *refinement* [Munkres]:

> A collection $\mathcal{A}$ of subsets of the space $X$ is said to have **order** $m+1$ if some point of $X$ lies in $m+1$ elements of $\mathcal{A}$, and no point of $X$ lies in more than $m+1$ elements of $\mathcal{A}$.
>
> Given a collection $\mathcal{A}$ of subsets of $X$, a collection $\mathcal{B}$ is said to **refine** $\mathcal{A}$, or to be a **refinement** of $\mathcal{A}$, if for each element $B$ of $\mathcal{B}$, there is an element $A$ of $\mathcal{A}$ such that $B \subseteq A$.

With these notions we can define the dimension of topological space [Munkres]:

> A space $X$ is said to be **finite dimensional** if there is some integer $m$ such that for every open covering $\mathcal{A}$ of $X$, there is an open covering $\mathcal{B}$ of $X$ that refines $\mathcal{A}$ and has order at most $m+1$. The **topological dimension** of $X$ is defined to be the smallest value of $m$ for which this statement holds; we denote it by $\dim X$.

The nice thing about this definition is that, in some major cases, it does agree with other notions of dimension:

- Any compact subspace $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ has dimension $\leq n$. E.g. $[0,1]  \subset \mathbb{R}$ has dimension $1$.
- Any compact $m$-manifold has dimension $m$.

You can read more about this definition on the Wikipedia article on [Lebesgue covering dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_covering_dimension).

Comment: I was reading this answer, and I though that, perhaps, you could add what "order" means, here: like this, it's a bit of a correspendence of unknown words. ;)

Comment: @G.Sassatelli You're absolutely right. I've added the definitions of order and refinement :)

Comment: @steamyRoot thank you so much for such a nice explanations

Comment: You an also define it inductively, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_dimension This agrees with the covering dimension when $X$ is separable metric.