# Are these following $2$ sets manifolds?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, analysis, derivatives, differential-geometry

I need to determine whether the sets:

1. $M=\lbrace (x,y,z,w)\in\Bbb R^4:x^3+y^3+z^3+w^3=1\rbrace$ in $\Bbb R^4$
2. $N=\lbrace (x,y,z,w)\in\Bbb R^4:x^3+y^3+z^3+w^3=1,w=-1\rbrace$ in $\Bbb R^4$

I think $M$ is a $3$-dimensional manifold because by the definition in the picture below, as we can solve for $x$ in terms of the remaining $3$ variables, $M$ is a manifold.

[image]

I think $N$ is a $2$-dimensional manifold because we can define $\Phi=x^3+y^3+z^3+w^3-1,\Psi=w+1$ and after some calculation, we can find:

$\nabla \Phi=(3x^2,3y^2,3z^2,3w^2),\nabla\Psi=(0,0,0,1)$.

Claim: these $2$ vectors are linearly independent.

Proof:

Suppose, in order to get a contradicton, that these vectors are linearly dependent, then $\nabla \Phi=\alpha\nabla\Psi$ for some $\alpha\ne 0$.

Then $3x^2=3y^2=3z^2=\alpha\cdot 0=0\Rightarrow x=y=z=0$, so $w^3=1$, but it contradicts $w=-1$. So they are always linearly independent.

Thus $N$ is a manifold.

Could some one please check if I am correct?

For 1., what I an concerning is that I have just found this post:

[How to formally prove that the set $x^2 + y^2 -z^2 = a$ is not a manifold for $a=0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1914923/how-to-formally-prove-that-the-set-x2-y2-z2-a-is-not-a-manifold-for-a)

I have learnt too little about manifold to understand the question together wih its answer. But it says that the set $(x,y,z):x^2+y^2-z^2=a$ is not a manifold when $a=0$. It seems that for this set, $x$ can also be solve as a function of the remaining $2$ variables.

So may I please ask where is the difference?

Any help would be appreciate. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as a $C^1$ (or even differentiable) function, however!